# Why does using Collections.emptySet() with generics work in assignment but not as a method parameter?

Tags: java, generics, collections, type-inference

So, I have a class with a constructor like this:

```
public FilterList(Set<Integer> labels) {
    ...
}
```

and I want to construct a new `FilterList` object with an empty set. Following Joshua Bloch's advice in his book Effective Java, I don't want to create a new object for the empty set; I'll just use `Collections.emptySet()` instead:

```
FilterList emptyList = new FilterList(Collections.emptySet());
```

This gives me an error, complaining that `java.util.Set<java.lang.Object>` is not a `java.util.Set<java.lang.Integer>`. OK, how about this:

```
FilterList emptyList = new FilterList((Set<Integer>)Collections.emptySet());
```

This also gives me an error! Ok, how about this:

```
Set<Integer> empty = Collections.emptySet();
FilterList emptyList = new FilterList(empty);
```

Hey, it works! But why? After all, Java doesn't have type inference, which is why you get an unchecked conversion warning if you do `Set<Integer> foo = new TreeSet()` instead of `Set<Integer> foo = new TreeSet<Integer>()`. But `Set<Integer> empty = Collections.emptySet();` works without even a warning. Why is that?

Comment: all the answers below are correct, but what I don't get is: why would you initialize your collection with an emptyList instead of calling a default constructor without parameters? Every collection I know has a constructor with an existing collection and an empty constructor.

Comment: Interestingly, the following DOES compile: `FilterList emptyList = new FilterList((Set<Integer>)(Set<? extends Object>)Collections.emptySet());`

Comment: Another pretty funny example: `Set<Integer> emptySet = (Set<Integer>)Collections.emptySet();` does not compile.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The short answer is - that's a limitation of the type inference in Java's generic system.  It can infer generic types against concrete variables, but not against method parameters.

I *suspect* this is because methods are dispatched dynamically depending on the runtime class of the owning object, so at compile time (when **all** generic information is resolved) you can't actually know for sure what the class of the method parameter will be and hence can't infer.  Variable declarations are nice and constant, so you can.

Someone else might be able to give more detail and/or a nice link. :-)

In any case, you can always specify the type parameters explicitly for generic calls like so:

```
Collections.<Integer>emptySet();
```

or even several parameters at once, e.g.

```
Collections.<String, Boolean>emptyMap(); // Returns a Map<String, Boolean>
```

This often looks a little cleaner than having to cast, in cases where inference doesn't kick in.

Comment: +1 for good explanation of the why. I wish one could mark two answers correct in SO :)

Comment: I know the compiler won't look at method invocation for context when inferring, but I'm not sure why. At least for private or `final` methods, it should be possible to do inferencing.

Comment: @Hank: or `static` methods, which are resolved at compile time too.  Still - it *doesn't*, which I guess is the main point.

Comment: "I suspect this is because methods are dispatched dynamically depending on the runtime class of the owning object, so at compile time...you can't actually know for sure what the class of the method parameter will be and hence can't infer." In that case why doesn't the version with the type cast work?

Comment: Due to method overloading it is impossible to infer the type in expresssion like this `new FilterList(Collection.emptySet())` since you can have `FilterList(Set<Integer>)` as well as `FilterList(Set<String>)` and so the complier has no idea which one to choose.

Comment: "I suspect this is because methods are dispatched dynamically depending on the runtime class of the owning object". I'm not sure if it's the same thing, but which version of an overloaded method to call is determined at compile time: https://ampersand.space/blog/2007/1/12/java-overload/

Answer (score 7):

try

```
FilterList emptyList = new FilterList(Collections.<Integer>emptySet());
```

You can force the type parameter for methods that have them, in cases where the inference isn't good enough, or to allow you to use subtypes; for example:

```
// forces use of ArrayList as parameter instead of the infered List
List<String> l = someObject.<ArrayList<String> methodThatTakesTypeParamForReturnType();
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to do this:

```
FilterList emptyList = new FilterList(java.util.Collections.<Integer>emptySet());
```

That tells the `emptySet` method that its generic parameter should explicitly by `Integer` instead of the default `Object`. And yes, the syntax is completely funky and non-intuitive for this. :)

Comment: I was not aware of that syntex, thanks! But I still wonder why that syntax is not necessary in the variable assignment.

Comment: See Andrzej Doyle's answer. I believe it is a good explanation.

Comment: You don't need `new` there. In fact I don't think it will compile with it.

Answer (score 5):

Java does have a type inference, it's just pretty limited. If you are interested in knowing exactly how it works and what its limitations are, this is a really good read:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html#Type%2BArgument%2BInference